# Pre-garbling does not improve capacity of a channel

Tags: linear-algebra, it.information-theory, stochastic-matrices

Suppose ABC=B for some column stochastic matrices A, B, and C.
Can the following implication be made without further restrictions:
There necessarily exists a column stochastic matrix D such that DB=BC?

I think this is implicated by lemma 1 of [Rauh et al. - Coarse-graining and the Blackwell order](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07602) and the theorem of Blackwell, Sherman and Stein.
Unfortunately the paper contains just a very limited proof. It uses the statement that the capacity of a pre-garbling is bounded by the original experiment/channel and states this as a well-known fact.

My current efforts to prove this special step by myself failed. I would therefore appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I fixed the typo while changing the arXiv link to point to the PDF, but I was sorry to have to get rid of the phrase "I would … appreciate any assistants."

Comment: "The given example": example of what? "example is implicated": how can one imply/implicate an example? since I don't guess what is meant, I haven't edited this.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected that one. The term "example" was a remnant of an earlier version of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Pre-garbling is equivalent to changing the input distribution to the channel defined by $B$. Since the capacity of $B$ is given by maximising the mutual information between the input and the output of the channel over all possible input distributions you cannot increase the capacity by pre-garbling.